# regex search date in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to search for a date at a string with javascript. For example:

```
string.search(dateReg);
```

Then, show the date when I find it.

I found a really nice regex at (http://regexr.com/3eoib). It works on my string: `27.11.` or `27.11.2016`, but it does not work on `abcde 27.11.2016 fghi` (result: `-1`).

The regex can't find the date because of these charaters in front and behind the date :/. I googled for 2 hours but didn't found an anwser (how to change the regex the right way?). I also looked at the basis regex-expressions but I coundn't find an answer :/.

Does someone know how to filter the date out of the string?

Thank you :-).

Comment: Are trying to match date similar to 27-11-2016 or just 27.11.2016?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978510/regex-to-match-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the same code, but replace $ and ^ with regex word boundry `\b`. The code should look like this:

```
(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})(?=\W)|\b(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])?|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)?)))(?=\W)|\b(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\4)?(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})?(?=\b)
```

The code above will match:

> 30/04/2016
>
> 31/05/2016

But it will not match:

> 31/04/2016
>
> 32/05/2016

and it will match any date that has a string before/after it:

> abcde ***27.11.2016***

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Hs2sjW/5

**Update:**

The previous code could have some issues. The best way to do this is to check date pattern first, then check the validity of the date. The first regex that check the date pattern could be something like this:

```
\d{2}[-.\/]\d{2}(?:[-.\/]\d{2}(\d{2})?)?
```

Then check the validity of the date with your regex. Here is a working javascript:

```js
var myString = "Test 22/10/20 Test"; //Could be any String
var myRegexp = /\d{2}[-.\/]\d{2}(?:[-.\/]\d{2}(\d{2})?)?/g; //Check pattern only
var validDate = /(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])?|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)?)))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\4)?(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})?$/g; //Check the validity of the date
myString = myRegexp.exec(myString)
myString = validDate.exec(myString[0])
console.log(myString[0])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It's one thing to match a date pattern, another to check validity. I don't think it's a good idea to combine the two. Given 29/2/2015, the above regular expression matches "29/2/", also for 29/2/2000, which is a valid date. It seems to me to be much simpler to first match the pattern with something like `/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/`, then check if it's valid since it seems the second step to validate the date is required anyway.

Comment: @RobG Thank you for the feedback. I agree with you. Combing the two things in one code is less efficient. In my Regex, It seems that Feb 29 is the only date that is causing issues. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @RobG I updated the code. It seems to recognize the difference between 29/2/2000 and 29/2/2015 now.

Comment: @Ibrahim Hm, I does not match to the 29,30 and 31th of a month (29.12) :/.

Comment: @SliniElf I updated my answer. Check out the updated javescript.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you!

```
/(\d{1,2}[\.\/]){2,2}(\d{2,4})?/g
```