# Regex to search a file with date in the middle

Tags: python, regex, unix

I am trying to create a Regex that will match a file that has date in the middle: The filename looks something like this

```
"Weekly Score 07.27.2018 Report.csv"
"Weekly Score 08.03.2018 Report.csv"
```

The folder can have multiple files like these, I want to match any file with this pattern.

I am writing a python code for this on a server.

Comment: Whats your expected output exactly?

Comment: @heemayl I want a regex that I can use to search these kind of files.

Comment: @aakib use Pythex to help you generate what you want: https://pythex.org/

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978510/regex-to-match-date

Comment: @KyleC Pythex is so simple and helpful. Thanks

Comment: Solution:   Weekly Score [0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4} Report.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pattern `r"\s\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s"`

**Ex:**

```
import re

l = ["Weekly Score 07.27.2018 Report.csv", "Weekly Score 08.03.2018 Report.csv", "Weekly Score Report.csv"]
for i in l:
    m = re.search(r"\s\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s", i) #or m = re.match(r"Weekly Score \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} Report.csv", i)
    if m:   #Has Date in name.
        print(m.group())
```

**Output:**

```
 07.27.2018 
 08.03.2018
```

Comment: Solution:   Weekly Score [0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4} Report.csv

Answer (score 0):

Use (0?[1-9]|1[012]).(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]).\d{4}:

```
import re

files = ["Weekly Score 07.27.2018 Report.csv", "Weekly Score 08.03.2018 Report.csv"]
result = []

for filename in files:
    m = re.search(r"\s(0?[1-9]|1[012])\.(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.\d{4}\s", filename)
    if m:
        result.append(m.group())

print(result)
```

- `(0?[1-9]|1[012])` - months (from 01 to 12)
- `(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` - days (from 01 to 31).
- `\d{4}` - years.

Comment: What if I want to neglect the search from date point of view to just numeric values. Something like this [Weely] [Score] [Search field that can have 2 digits for month.field that can have 2 digits for day.field that have 4 digits for year] [Report].csv

Comment: @Aakib than it should be simple regex with `\d{n}` for n-length number instead of patterns for days and months ranges.

Comment: Solution:   Weekly Score [0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4} Report.csv

Comment: @Aakib you can write `\d{n}` instead of `[0-9]{n}`. In OP you said, that you need to find a date. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Regex to match datetime as that could lead to false positives.

Get files using `glob`, iterate over them, check for the datetime pattern with `datetime.datetime.strptime` on the space separated third field:

```
import glob
import datetime

files = glob.iglob('Weekly Score * Report.csv')  # Make necessary changes
                                                 # on the pattern, if you want
for file_name in files:
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(file_name.split()[2], '%m.%d.%Y')
    except ValueError:
        continue
    # Matched; do stuffs
    print(file_name)
```

**Example:**

```
In [960]: files = ["Weekly Score 07.27.2018 Report.csv", "Weekly Score 08.03.2018 Report.csv", "Weekly Score 15.23.2018 Report.csv"]

In [961]: for file_name in files:
     ...:     try:
     ...:         datetime.datetime.strptime(file_name.split()[2], '%m.%d.%Y')
     ...:     except ValueError:
     ...:         continue
     ...:     print(file_name)
     ...: 
     ...:         
Weekly Score 07.27.2018 Report.csv
Weekly Score 08.03.2018 Report.csv
```

Comment: What if I want to neglect the search from date point of view to just numeric values. Something like this [Weely] [Score] [Search field that can have 2 digits for month.field that can have 2 digits for day.field that have 4 digits for year] [Report].csv

Comment: @Aakib It's pretty simple: match the pattern in strptime. I suggest you to look at the [`datetime.datetime.strptime` doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Comment: Solution:   Weekly Score [0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4} Report.csv

Comment: @Aakib Well...You seemed to misunderstand the point of my answer and my _urge_ to not use Regex to match any datetime. Does the _solution_ you provided account for a file like `Weekly Score 99.99.9999 Report.csv` ? It's not a valid datetime but your solution would match it happily. Anyways, good luck!