# Apply regex to select items in a list

Tags: python, regex

Considering a list of tickers as the following below:

```
tickers = ['EWZ US 05/29/20 C31','HSI US 12/30/20 C24900', 'SKG1C 24', 'S H1P 49']
```

How I can apply a filter to select only tickers that have a date? I'm try the following:

```
import re
tickers_off = [re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)', x) for x in tickers]
```

output expected:

```
['EWZ US 05/29/20 C31','HSI US 12/30/20 C24900']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use your current regex to *filter* the list items:

```py
import re
tickers = ['EWZ US 05/29/20 C31','HSI US 12/30/20 C24900', 'SKG1C 24', 'S H1P 49']
rx = re.compile(r'\d+/\d+/\d+')
print( list(filter(rx.search, tickers)) )
# => ['EWZ US 05/29/20 C31', 'HSI US 12/30/20 C24900']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/N3oBRC).

You might want to have a bit more precise date pattern, say, one from [Regex to match Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978510/regex-to-match-date) or similar:

```py
r'\b(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(?:19|20)?\d{2}\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU7ozB/1).